# Is it possible set listener on multiple events being triggered together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to trigger a handler only if two events fire (ie. `scroll` AND `mousewheel`) from the same single action.

My first attempt is was:

```
 $('#right-nav').on('scroll mousewheel', function(event){ console.log('Fired') })
```

However here it's possible to trigger `scroll` without `mousewheel`, and to trigger `mousewheel` without `scroll`. Also If you trigger both, the function will execute twice.

I would like to execute only if the `mousewheel` also triggers  `scroll`, put simply, to catch the "single action that produced both events"

or vice versa, to execute only if `mousewheel` does Not trigger `scroll`

Is this possible? Is there anyway to tell if other events are coming?

Here is a playground jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/8028/

Comment: Have a look at [DOMMouseScroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMMouseScroll), that might be what you are looking for

Comment: It would be nice but its not supported by any modern browser

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to trigger two (or more) events at once.
But you always may think of the sequence of events if they may be related etc.
Remember that the JavaScript is a single thread so e.g. 
suppose that scroll event shall be before or after mousewheel event but within 100ms I will do:

```
var eventHappened = false ;

$(something).on('scroll', function(){
  if (eventHappened){
    // do the task I need for both events
  }
  else{
    eventHappened = true ;
    window.setTimeout(function(){ eventHappened = false ; }, 100);
  }
});

$(something).on('mousewheel', function(){
  if (eventHappened){
    // do the task I need for both events
  }
  else{
    eventHappened = true ;
    window.setTimeout(function(){ eventHappened = false ; }, 100);
  }
});
```

Comment: This wont work, as two individual scrolls (for example from the arrow key) will trigger the eventHappened event in scroll.

Comment: It is just an idea that one may adjust to the exact needs but remember that no two events will ever be fired as single. JavaScript is single threaded!

Comment: Also scrolling always trigger the scroll event multiple times, they would fire before setTimout

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @neojg's answer:

```
var scroll = false, mouse = false;

$(something).on('scroll', function(){
  if (mouse){
    // do the task I need for both events
  }
  else{
    scroll = true ;
    window.setTimeout(function(){ scroll = false ; }, 100);
  }
});

$(something).on('mousewheel', function(){
  if (scroll){
    // do the task I need for both events
  }
  else{
    mouse = true ;
    window.setTimeout(function(){ mouse = false ; }, 100);
  }
});
```